# OpenQA.Selenium.IllegalLocatorException when performing browser.ExecuteScript()

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I'm using Selenium ChromeDriver v2.9.248315. When I click a button that causes a page postback, I can no longer perform browser.ExecuteScript without it erroring. Also, if I attempt browser.Refresh(), I receive the same error. I'm completely stumped on how to proceed. I've attempted to load a new BrowserWindow from the existing browser title. I've attempted refreshing the BrowserWindow process. Any help would be appreciated/

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome"
browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(websiteUrl); 
string script = "console.log('test');";
// Works
browser.ExecuteScript(script)    
browser.Click<HtmlInputButton>("SaveChanges", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);    
// Click causes Postback, Script no longer works and throws the error
browser.ExecuteScript(script)
```

Also Reproduced By:

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome"
browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(websiteUrl); 
browser.Refresh();
string script = "console.log('test');";
browser.ExecuteScript(script)
```

Another Method to Repro:

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome"
browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(websiteUrl); 
// Refresh / Hard Refresh 
string script = "console.log('test');";
browser.ExecuteScript(script)
```

This works though:

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome"
browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(websiteUrl); 
// Empty Cache and Hard Reload (Ctrl + F5)
string script = "console.log('test');";
browser.ExecuteScript(script)
```

Failing Logs:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestJScriptExecutionException was unhandled by user code 
    BasicMessage=Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IllegalLocatorException' from assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.53.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f'.
    HResult (System.Exception)=-2146233088
    HResult=-2146233088
    Message=Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IllegalLocatorException' from assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.53.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f'.
    Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser
    StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<ExecuteScript>b__0()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
```

[image]

Comment: Shot in the dark here - this sounds like a timing issue since you said there's a postback, can you try inserting a Thread.Sleep(2000) in the line before you call ExecuteScript()?

Comment: I've tried putting a sleep but no luck. I think that when the page is Refreshed/Postback, the selenium chromedriver loses sync with the page.